# Opening Excel (.xls) file in IPhone

Tags: c#, asp.net, iphone, excel, ssrs-2008

**Task** : We need to send an email having an excel attachment(ex: filename.xls) from C# application

**Problem Statemet** : Unable to open the excel attachment in iPhone sent from C# application.

**Error** : Document cannot be viewed. File format is invalid.

Data is rendered from Report server and is written to an excel file using the following code:

```
byte[] bytes = rptAffirmativeTradeReportViewer.ServerReport.Render(format, null, out mimetype, out encoding,out filenameExtension, out streamids, out warnings);
string sfilename = filename.xls
        try
        {
            FileStream fs = File.Create(sFileName);
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            fs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

The above code geneates a file with the name filename.xls and contains the data.

The file will be then attached to an outlook and sent to users.

The users who use iPhone are not able to open the excel and are getting error.
The users who use Android are able to open the excel file.

Please help to let us know what needs to be done in order to open this file in iPhone.

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Answer (score 2):

```
UIWebView *webView = (UIWebView*)self.view;
self.actualFilePath = filePath;

NSLog(@"File Path %@",filePath);

NSString *mimeType = @"";
if ([fileType caseInsensitiveCompare:@"PDF"]==NSOrderedSame){
mimeType = @"application/pdf";
} else  if ([fileType caseInsensitiveCompare:@"DOC"]==NSOrderedSame){
mimeType = @"application/msword";
} else  if ([fileType caseInsensitiveCompare:@"XLS"]==NSOrderedSame){
mimeType = @"application/vnd.ms-excel";
}

[webView loadData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath] MIMEType:mimeType    textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

hope it helpful

Comment: Hi Huy Nghia -  To be frank, i didn't understand the answer.